# How to programmatically update the command attribute of an embedded, SQL connection

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

using c# openxml - I am attempting to open an excel file, bind to its connection.xml stream, and update the embedded SQL query. I am able to successfully replace individual character sequences withing the connection/command node, but attempting to explicitly set the command attribute (i.e. node.Attribute["command"].Value = select * from ....) is resulting in a corrupted

```
xmlDoc.Load(wkb.WorkbookPart.ConnectionsPart.GetStream());

csNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("*/*/*[@connection]");

csNode.Attributes["command"].Value = Regex.Replace(csNode.Attributes["command"].Value,        @"\(\[\w*\].\[\w*\].\[\w*\].\[\w*\].*\)", "(" + subQry + ")", RegexOptions.Multiline);

xmlDoc.Save(wkb.WorkbookPart.ConnectionsPart.GetStream()); 

wkb.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the only way to solve this issue, but I was able to correct it by deleting the original connections.xml stream and creating/attaching a new one with the correct value to the workbook.

```
 //select connections node from loaded xml Excel
 csNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("*/*/*[@connection]");

 //store original node values
 oldConnValue = csNode.Attributes["connection"].Value;
 oldCommValue = csNode.Attributes["command"].Value;

 //delete existing ConnectionsPart - to ensure that bleed-over data is not present
 wkb.WorkbookPart.DeletePart(wkb.WorkbookPart.ConnectionsPart);

 //create a replacement ConnectionsPart
 wkb.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<ConnectionsPart>();

 csNode.Attributes["connection"].Value = oldConnValue; //reassign existing connection value
 csNode.Attributes["command"].Value = baseQry;         //assign new query

 //save changes to stream
 xmlDoc.Save(wkb.WorkbookPart.ConnectionsPart.GetStream());
```